# JavaLangAccess and SharedSecrets in Java 9

Tags: java, java-9

It seems like the `SharedSecrets` and `JavaLangAccess` classes from the `sun.misc` package were removed in Java 9.

Are there any replacements in Java 9 for the functionality provided by these classes?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do using these classes?

Comment: Using the `newStringUnsafe` or `getEnumConstantsShared` methods, for example.

Comment: The internal newStringUnsafe and getEnumConstantsShared should never be used by code outside of the JDK core classes. The supported APIs are of course String(char[]) and Class::getEnumConstants.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Both the above classes are packaged in `jdk.internal.misc` package.

One way you can try and access them is by using the option

```
--add-exports <source-module>/<package>=<target-module>(,<target-module>)*
```

for your use case as :

```
--add-exports java.base/jdk.internal.misc=your.module
```

***Note***:- Disclaimer from *[JEP-261:Module System](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/261)* -

> **The `--add-exports` and `--add-opens` options must be used with great
>   care. You can use them to gain access to an internal API of a library
>   module, or even of the JDK itself, but you do so at your own risk: *If
>   that internal API is changed or removed then your library or
>   application will fail.***

Comment: That package appears to be [undocumented](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java.base-summary.html).  Is there any guarantee it will be present in future Java releases?  Or do developers assume the risk, just like they did when using sun.\* packages?

Comment: @VGR They might supposedly be removed in future releases I believe. Added the disclaimer from the JEP to specify that.

Comment: Developers should be strongly discouraged from using sun.*, jdk.internal.* and other JDK internal APIs. So I don't think it's a good idea to suggest the submitter move to use the new location of the internal shared secrets classes.

Comment: @AlanBateman I do second the point as already pointed out by VGR as well. Hence added the note to the answer as well. And I have just suggested *one way* on how this could be achieved not defining that as a must/should to be followed. And without a doubt, I would be glad to upvote an answer that could reflect details over the replacements to the mentioned classes and their functionalities.

Answer (score 2):

According to **[Bug#JDK-8137056](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8137056)**

> In preparation for JEP 160, **SharedSecrets and friend interfaces should
>   be moved out of 'sun.misc'** and located in a truly private package

And they are now available at **`jdk.internal.misc`**

> Move SharedSecrets and friends to jdk.internal.misc

Comment: Does that mean there is no requirement of exports for this package?

Comment: @ManiGrover if you are asking about `sun.misc` then, yes. And, as per my understanding, they won't exist actually.

Comment: Asking about the moved package jdk.internal.misc?

Comment: @ManiGrover You have to, which mentioned in other answer.

Comment: As an aside, wouldn't the concept of Shared Secrets be made obsolete by the implementation of modules? Don't modules allow you to provide special access paths between packages while preventing outside code from reaching it? Sort of a broader version of package-private access that allows a project to internally share code with itself without exposing implementation to other projects?