# How does the SharedSecrets mechanism work?

Tags: java

`jdk.internal.misc.SharedSecrets` describes itself as:

> A repository of "shared secrets", which are a mechanism for
>       calling implementation-private methods in another package without
>       using reflection. A package-private class implements a public
>       interface and provides the ability to call package-private methods
>       within that package; the object implementing that interface is
>       provided through a third package to which access is restricted.
>       This framework avoids the primary disadvantage of using reflection
>       for this purpose, namely the loss of compile-time checking.

Can someone please provide an example that demonstrates how this mechanism enables classes in one package to access package-private methods in a different package?

Comment: Since this technique works since Java 1.1 and Sun’s `SharedSecrets` is not much younger, there is no relevance to `[java-9]`. This is illustrated by the fact that the article you’ve cited in the answer is almost ten years old.

Comment: ....and the only relevant change in JDK9 about `SharedSecrets` I could find [was this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46612648/javalangaccess-and-sharedsecrets-in-java-9)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Quoting [Andrew John Hughes](https://web.archive.org/web/20220331012455/http://blog.fuseyism.com/index.php/2008/05/26/sharing-secrets/):

> When looking through OpenJDK for the VM project, I noticed that they have a rather interesting solution to this. This is encapsulated in sun.misc.SharedSecrets. This class provides access to instances of a number of public interfaces, such as sun.misc.JavaLangAccess. The actual implementations are provided as inner classes in the appropriate package e.g. java.lang, where it has access to the private and package-private variables and methods within.

Say that you have API classes scattered across multiple packages. You want them to be able to access each other's internals, without exposing them to end-users. What do you do?

#### Option 1: Without Java Modules

1. Create an "internal" package that will be omitted from the public Javadoc (e.g. **com.example.internal**)
2. Declare one or more interfaces in the internal package, referencing the private functionality you are trying to access.
3. Declare a public class (e.g. **SharedSecrets**) in the internal package to hold implementations of these interfaces.
4. Use static initializers in your API classes to get/set implementations of these interfaces from/to **SharedSecrets**.
5. Now, API classes can access each other's internals by piggybacking through a trusted intermediary (**SharedSecrets**).

#### Option 2: With Java Modules

1. Say you have two modules: **main** and **test**, and you want **test** to access private or package-private methods and fields inside **main**.
2. Declare a public class **SharedSecrets** inside the main module, in a non-exported package. For example: **main.internal.SharedSecrets**.
3. In **main**'s **module-info.java**, add `exports main.internal to test`.
4. Meaning, the package **main.internal** will only be accessible to module **test**.
5. Because **SharedSecrets** is public, anyone in **main** (even from different packages) can push bridge functions or fields into it. It actually works the other way as well (**test** can push bridge functions into **main**) but I've never needed to do this to date.
6. Now, anytime **test** wishes to access the internals of **main**, it simply piggybacks its calls through **SharedSecrets**.

This solution is especially nice because the resulting Javadoc and IDE auto-complete will look a lot cleaner.

### Concrete Example

```
External Users
├── external
│   └── EndUser.java
└── module-info.java

Library
├── library
│   ├── character
│   │   └── Character.java
│   ├── story
│   │   └── Story.java
│   └── internal
│       ├── SharedSecrets.java
│       └── SecretCharacter.java
└── module-info.java
```

- We want to expose `Character`'s internals to `Story` without `EndUser` gaining access.

---

End-user code

---

**external/EndUser.java:**

```
package external;

import library.character.Character;
import library.story.Story;

public class EndUser
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Story story = new Story();
        story.introduce(Character.HARRY_POTTER);
        story.introduce(Character.RON_WEASLEY);
        story.introduce(Character.HERMIONE_GRANGER);
    }
}
```

**module-info.java:**

```
module external
{
    requires library;
}
```

---

Library code

---

**library/story/Story.java**

```
package library.story;

import library.character.Character;
import library.internal.SecretCharacter;
import library.internal.SharedSecrets;

public final class Story
{
    private static final SharedSecrets sharedSecrets =
      SharedSecrets.INSTANCE;

    public void introduce(Character character)
    {
        System.out.println(character.name() + " enters the room and says: " + 
          sharedSecrets.secretCharacter.getPhrase(character));
    }
}
```

**library/character/Character.java:**

```
package library.character;

import library.internal.SecretCharacter;
import library.internal.SharedSecrets;

public enum Character
{
    HARRY_POTTER
    {
        @Override
        String getPhrase()
        {
            return "Your bird, there was nothing I could do. He just caught fire.";
        }
    },
    RON_WEASLEY
    {
        @Override
        String getPhrase()
        {
            return "Who are you and what have you done with Hermione Granger?";
        }
    },
    HERMIONE_GRANGER
    {
        @Override
        String getPhrase()
        {
            return "I'm not an owl!";
        }
    };

    static
    {
        SharedSecrets.INSTANCE.secretCharacter = new SecretCharacter()
        {
            @Override
            public String getPhrase(Character character)
            {
                return character.getPhrase();
            }
        };
    }

    abstract String getPhrase();
}
```

**library/internal/SharedSecrets.java:**

```
package library.internal;

public enum SharedSecrets
{
    INSTANCE;
    public SecretCharacter secretCharacter;
}
```

**library/internal/SecretCharacter.java:**

```
package library.internal;

import library.character.Character;

public interface SecretCharacter
{
    String getPhrase(Character character);
}
```

**module-info.java:**

```
module library
{
    exports library.character;
    exports library.story;
}
```

**Output**

> HARRY_POTTER enters the room and says: Your bird, there was nothing I could do. He just caught fire.
>
> RON_WEASLEY enters the room and says: Who are you and what have you done with Hermione Granger?
>
> HERMIONE_GRANGER enters the room and says: I'm not an owl!

**Notice**

- `Character.getPhrase()` is package-protected.
- `Story` is located in a different package.
- Normally `Story` wouldn't be able to invoke `Character.getPhrase()`; however, `SharedSecrets` allows `Character` to share access with classes that it trusts.
- `Story` invokes `SharedSecrets.INSTANCE.secretCharacter` which uses an anonymous nested class to access `Character`'s internals.
- `Story` can access `SharedSecrets` because the two are located in the same module, but external users cannot access it because `module-info.java` does not export that package.

Comment: As the code is written it will raise a NullPointerException as the Story class will be initialized first by EndUser main, however, SharedSecrets.INSTANCE.secretCharacter is null when Story.secretCharacter is set.  Better to not have static secretCharacter  variable in Story.

Comment: @Ceki You are right. I updated the example code to match what I actually do in my libraries. This should fix the problem.

Comment: It's a small world.