# Is it possible to use SharedSecrets across Java modules?

Tags: java, java-module, module-info

Given:

- Modules `A` and `B`, where `B` imports `A`.
- Module `A` exports `external.class1`. It defines but does not export `external.class1.secretProvider`, `internal.SharedSecrets` and `internal.class2` (more on these below).
- Module `A` uses [the SharedSecrets mechanism](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46723089/14731) to grant `external.class1` access to private methods in `internal.class2` using `external.class1.secretProvider`.

I wish to grant `external.class3` (defined in Module `B`) access to private methods in `internal.class2` but seeing as `internal.SharedSecrets` and `external.class1.secretProvider` are not exported by `A` I have no way of doing so.

Is there a way for `B` to access to `A`'s secrets without exporting them for the whole world to see?

Comment: Why not use a qualified export? `exports external.class1.secretProvider to B`.. If I understand the question correct that's what you're looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a way for B to access to A's secrets without exporting them
>   for the whole world to see?

If I am not getting the question wrong, you can use *qualified exports* to make sure you export those packages just to a specific (list of) module. You can do so as :

```
module A {
    exports external.class1.secretProvider to B;
    exports internal.SharedSecrets to B;
    // ... rest of your declarations
}
```

Comment: Makes sense to me. I didn't consider this option because most tutorials I found did not cover qualified exports. I ended up finding https://www.oracle.com/corporate/features/understanding-java-9-modules.html which does. Thank you.