# Error while executing the compiled jar file

Tags: java, exception, jar, gif

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: class Animation (in unnamed module @0x365608eb) cannot access class com.sun.imageio.plugins.gif.GIFImageReader (in module java.desktop) because module java.desktop does not export com.sun.imageio.plugins.gif to unnamed module

```
ImageReader ir = new GIFImageReader(new GIFImageReaderSpi());
ir.setInput(inputStream);
```

Comment: Check if this answers your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53633788/java-lang-illegalaccesserror-cannot-access-class-because-module-does-not-export

Comment: I did not understand where to write this when running the code. Could you explain? I run my jar through a .bat file that says: @echo off

java -Xms1024M -Xmx1024M -jar myjar.jar
pause

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.