# Jade Platform : Error in Connecting two remote platforms

Tags: java, agents-jade

I want to connect two jade platform on a separate pcs on local network.

I run the jade platform using command

```
java -cp lib/jade.jar jade.Boot -gui
```

everything work fine but when i tried to add one platform to other by select from the gui (remote platforms) menu then select add (platform via ams aid) then write ams guid which is

```
ams@192.168.0.103:1099/JADE
```

and the address of it which is

```
http://192.168.0.103:7778/acc
```

i got this error on the other pc:

```
jade.mtp.http.HTTPServer$ServerThread run
WARNING: HTTPServer error:
jade.mtp.MTPException: java.lang.IllegalAccessException: 
class jade.mtp.http.XMLCodec cannot access class
com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser (in 
module java.xml) because module java.xml does not export 
com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp to unnamed module @49b70bc7
```

and when i run two platforms on the same pc(for sure with diffrent local port) it works fine.

Comment: Does it work with java 8?

Comment: You might want to check other questions like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53633788/java-lang-illegalaccesserror-cannot-access-class-because-module-does-not-export