# It says status":500,"error":"Internal Server Error on soapui when I request for a response

Tags: soap, soapui, ws-security

This endpoint class
correlate the methods from request and response classes from the target as I put the request and response classes in target directory.

```
package com.security.test;

import org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.annotation.Endpoint;
import org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.annotation.PayloadRoot;
import org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.annotation.RequestPayload;
import org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.annotation.ResponsePayload;
import security.test.GetTestRequest;
import security.test.GetTestResponse;
@Endpoint
public class TestEndpoint {
private final String NAMESPACE_URI="http://security/test";
    @PayloadRoot(namespace = NAMESPACE_URI, localPart = "getTestRequest")
    @ResponsePayload
public GetTestResponse securityResponse(@RequestPayload GetTestRequest request){

    GetTestResponse response = new GetTestResponse();

    String given=request.getGivenString();
    int myAge=given.length();
     response.setLength(myAge);
    System.out.println(response);
    return response;
}
}
```

All the dependencies from pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.3</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>test</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>test</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>18</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web-services</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>wsdl4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>wsdl4j</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.ws</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-ws-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.xml.wss</groupId>
            <artifactId>xws-security</artifactId>
            <version>3.0</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>javax.xml.crypto</groupId>
                    <artifactId>xmldsig</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>javax.activation</groupId>
                    <artifactId>activation</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>jaxb2-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>xjc</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>xjc</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <sources>
                        <source>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/test.xsd</source>
                    </sources>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

using xwsInterceptor it intercept the request and looks for authentication using simple passwordvalidationCallHandler
This webSConfig class extends WsConfigurerAdapter

```
{
    @Bean
    public ServletRegistrationBean messageDispatcherServlet(ApplicationContext applicationContext) {
        MessageDispatcherServlet servlet = new MessageDispatcherServlet();
        servlet.setApplicationContext(applicationContext);
        servlet.setTransformWsdlLocations(true);
        return new ServletRegistrationBean(servlet, "/ws/*");
    }

    @Bean(name = "test")
    public DefaultWsdl11Definition defaultWsdl11Definition(XsdSchema testSchema) {
        DefaultWsdl11Definition wsdl11Definition = new DefaultWsdl11Definition();
        wsdl11Definition.setPortTypeName("TestPort");
        wsdl11Definition.setLocationUri("/ws");
        wsdl11Definition.setTargetNamespace("http://security/test");
        wsdl11Definition.setSchema(testSchema);
        return wsdl11Definition;
    }

    @Bean
    public XsdSchema testSchema() {
        return new SimpleXsdSchema(new ClassPathResource("test.xsd"));
    }
    @Bean
    public XwsSecurityInterceptor securityInterceptor() {
        XwsSecurityInterceptor securityInterceptor = new XwsSecurityInterceptor();
        securityInterceptor.setCallbackHandler(callbackHandler());
        securityInterceptor.setPolicyConfiguration(new ClassPathResource("securityPolicy.xml"));
        return securityInterceptor;
    }
    @Bean
    public CallbackHandler callbackHandler() {
        SimplePasswordValidationCallbackHandler callbackHandler = new SimplePasswordValidationCallbackHandler();
        callbackHandler.setUsersMap(Collections.singletonMap("admin", "pwd123"));
        return callbackHandler;
    }
    @Override
    public void addInterceptors(List<EndpointInterceptor> interceptors) {
        interceptors.add(securityInterceptor());
    }
}
```

however, I am not getting the right response,It even does not response about the security issue it responses status":500,"error":"Internal Server Error on soapUi while I run the request. and the intellij response as

java.lang.IllegalAccessError: class com.sun.xml.wss.impl.SecurableSoapMessage (in unnamed module @0x60285225) cannot access class com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.security.Init (in module java.xml.crypto) because module java.xml.crypto does not export com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.security to unnamed module @0x60285225

Comment: Does this answer your question? [java.lang.IllegalAccessError: cannot access class because module does not export to unnamed module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53633788/java-lang-illegalaccesserror-cannot-access-class-because-module-does-not-export)